# Error building my app to my ipod touch:building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

So I finished coding my app, and downloaded the development profile n all that good stuff with the entitlements, etc; but I get these warnings:

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

as well as a whole bunch of errors which seem like the code does not recognize its own syntax. How do i fix this?
Update:
"Looks like your project or target may be misconfigured. Look at your build settings and verify that your Base SDK is an iOS Device SDK, and not an iOS Simulator SDK. Set your Architectures to Standard" - mirzapirza
I set the iOS device to 3.2 sdk and set the build to the standard architecture armv6 armv7.
However, now 14,00+ errors along with a "warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2" crops up. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I ended up doing is creating a new xcode project and just copy-pasted all the code from the old project to the new project. Now it works fine.

Comment: I know this is old but still I will comment. You haven't really solved the problem more then likely you would have changed something in the settings. Would it not have been best to try and resolve it so if in the future you had the same problem you can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project or target may be misconfigured. Look at your build settings and verify that your Base SDK is an iOS Device SDK, and not an iOS Simulator SDK. Set your Architectures to Standard.

Comment: yes, they are set to iOS Device 3.2 sdk and standard architecture armv6 armv7. still not working. Now I get 14,00+ errors, with a:: warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem - the solution was to remove the extra simulator-related entry from the "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" setting.

The only value you need associated with that key should be "$(inherited)".   This will cause the linker to acquire the framework libs from the appropriate frameworks directory based on the SDK selected for your project.