# device not working with mapkit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

my device doenst work at all when i load an project that contains any mapkit framework files
it says

ld: warning: in /APP/MapKit.framework/MapKit, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

and it doesnt let me test it on the device, however when i load this on my simulator it works.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this post help you : [Error building my app to my ipod touch:building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681598/error-building-my-app-to-my-ipod-touchbuilding-with-targeted-device-family-set)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be loading MapKit from the wrong directory; it's somehow trying to link against the simulator MapKit. Switch to the simulator build, right-click the framework, and make the path "relative to SDK directory" or so, and then switch back to the device build.

Alternatively, delete and re-add MapKit under "Add Existing Frameworks", which should do it correctly.