# MapKit works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, mapkit

When I call my map view controller on a device, the app just gets stuck, nothing happens, XCode doesn't even throw an error.
But the same code works just fine on the simulator. My code for presenting map view:

```
-(IBAction)mapButtonAction
{
   //storyboard
   UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   //navigation controller
   MapViewController *vc=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
   vc.coordinates = coordinates;
   vc.locationName = locationName;
   //warp as UINavigationController
   UINavigationController *vc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
   [[self navigationController] presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I tried remove and add again MapKit and CoreLocation frameworks, restart XCode, also checked my base SDK is iOS 6.1  and remove and rebuild app on device. When I make the map view root view controller it loads just fine.
B.T.W my device is iPhone 4, internet connection and gps working just fine and in privacy settings under gps app is aproved. Any ideas?!

Comment: Any reason you're presenting a modal view controller that way? Why not use a segue and let the storyboard do all the initialising for you?

Comment: Nop, just use to work this way, i adding my uibutton programmatically so it easier for me that way

Comment: Add the button programatically, then add a segue in the storyboard called 'MapSegue' and point it to the 'MapViewController'. Then in `mapButtonAction` just do... `[self performSegue:@"MapSegue"];`

Comment: Thanks, but its the same, working on simulator stuck on device.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to see what is / isn't happening. Or adding some NSLog messages at the least?

Comment: Yes, i did add nslog before button action, after, and on map view did load, only the log before works on device after it all freaze.

Comment: Can you log in the actual MapViewController. Maybe something in there is going wrong. Also, add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: When i make the map view as the root view controller it loads just fine, and like i said its also loads on simulator. breakpoint shows nothing special except maybe "semaphore_wait_trap" on the main thread

Comment: Hmm... again, why are you creating a UINavigationController? Ideally, if you're going to be using a Nav Controller then you probably want it at the base of your entire storyboard. i.e. The Nav Controller is the `InitialViewController` and the first view is the `RootViewController` of your navcontroller.

Comment: I did it just to see if the problem is in the map view  controller, anyway i think problem is somewhere in the framework or how the device approach it unlike the simulator.

Comment: If that was the case there'd be a lot more problems with it. I've used MapKit before with no problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4241372/1333294 ,why cant i find "relative to SDK directory" anywhere on right click?!